# How to get the weather description data and icon along with temp data from openweathermap in flutter?

Tags: flutter, openweathermap

I managed to get the temp data from the openweathermap. I managed to get the "main" data from this JSON from the internet. But see the weather field, the description is there but can't extract it. There it says "clear", and icon "01d". I will also get icon into flutter, which there is a URL of the images like for example somelink/01d.png and I will get this and load it dynamically:

```
{"coord":{"lon":28.9833,"lat":41.0351},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":15.87,"feels_like":15.16,"temp_min":15.04,"temp_max":17.09,"pressure":1024,"humidity":63},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.09,"deg":120},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1668078936,"sys":{"type":1,"id":6970,"country":"TR","sunrise":1668055522,"sunset":1668091839},"timezone":10800,"id":745042,"name":"Istanbul","cod":200}
```

The thing is, there are several ways I could do this. Futurebuilder inside futurebuilder, I don't know how this works. Or, return an array of data from the fetch function. I am not sure how to do that. I am completely puzzled. Here is my simplified code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TempModel {
  final double temp;
  final double feels_like;
  final double temp_min;
  final double temp_max;
  final int pressure;
  final int humidity;

  TempModel({
    required this.temp,
    required this.feels_like,
    required this.temp_min,
    required this.temp_max,
    required this.pressure,
    required this.humidity,
  });

  factory TempModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TempModel(
      temp: json['temp'],
      feels_like: json['feels_like'],
      temp_min: json['temp_min'],
      temp_max: json['temp_max'],
      pressure: json['pressure'],
      humidity: json['humidity'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['temp'] = temp;
    data['feels_like'] = feels_like;
    data['temp_min'] = temp_min;
    data['temp_max'] = temp_max;
    data['pressure'] = pressure;
    data['humidity'] = humidity;
    return data;
  }
}

class WeatherModel {
  final TempModel main;

  WeatherModel({
    required this.main,
  });

  factory WeatherModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return WeatherModel(
      main: TempModel.fromJson(json['main']),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['main'] = main;
    return data;
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const TestPage());

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String sehir1 = 'İstanbul';
  final String sehir2 = 'Ankara';
  final String sehir3 = 'İzmir';

  Future<WeatherModel?> fetchWeather(String sehir) async {
    //default olarak.

    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$sehir&units=metric&appid=666319c58bc57caab32599c61b82c50e'));
    print(response.body);
    print("");
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        WeatherModel weatherModel =
            WeatherModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        return weatherModel;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString(), name: "error");
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: fetchWeather(sehir1),
                builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<WeatherModel?> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Image.network(
                              'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d.png'),
                          Text('$sehir1 Hava Durumu'),
                          Text(
                              'Hava sıcaklığı ${snapshot.data!.main.temp.toString()}'),
                          Text(
                              'Hissedilen sıcaklık ${snapshot.data!.main.feels_like.toString()}'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weather` is a list:

```json
{
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ]
}
```

You have to get the values using its index:

```dart
${snapshot.data!.weather[0].icon}
```

Edit: I see that your model does not accounts entire json. Here's the full one:

```dart
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final weather = weatherFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

class Weather {
    Weather({
        required this.coord,
        required this.weather,
        required this.base,
        required this.main,
        required this.visibility,
        required this.wind,
        required this.clouds,
        required this.dt,
        required this.sys,
        required this.timezone,
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.cod,
    });

    final Coord coord;
    final List<WeatherElement> weather;
    final String base;
    final Main main;
    final int visibility;
    final Wind wind;
    final Clouds clouds;
    final int dt;
    final Sys sys;
    final int timezone;
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final int cod;

    factory Weather.fromRawJson(String str) => Weather.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Weather(
        coord: Coord.fromJson(json["coord"]),
        weather: List<WeatherElement>.from(json["weather"].map((x) => WeatherElement.fromJson(x))),
        base: json["base"],
        main: Main.fromJson(json["main"]),
        visibility: json["visibility"],
        wind: Wind.fromJson(json["wind"]),
        clouds: Clouds.fromJson(json["clouds"]),
        dt: json["dt"],
        sys: Sys.fromJson(json["sys"]),
        timezone: json["timezone"],
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        cod: json["cod"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "coord": coord.toJson(),
        "weather": List<dynamic>.from(weather.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "base": base,
        "main": main.toJson(),
        "visibility": visibility,
        "wind": wind.toJson(),
        "clouds": clouds.toJson(),
        "dt": dt,
        "sys": sys.toJson(),
        "timezone": timezone,
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "cod": cod,
    };
}

class Clouds {
    Clouds({
        required this.all,
    });

    final int all;

    factory Clouds.fromRawJson(String str) => Clouds.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Clouds.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Clouds(
        all: json["all"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "all": all,
    };
}

class Coord {
    Coord({
        required this.lon,
        required this.lat,
    });

    final double lon;
    final double lat;

    factory Coord.fromRawJson(String str) => Coord.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Coord.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Coord(
        lon: json["lon"].toDouble(),
        lat: json["lat"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lon": lon,
        "lat": lat,
    };
}

class Main {
    Main({
        required this.temp,
        required this.feelsLike,
        required this.tempMin,
        required this.tempMax,
        required this.pressure,
        required this.humidity,
    });

    final double temp;
    final double feelsLike;
    final double tempMin;
    final double tempMax;
    final int pressure;
    final int humidity;

    factory Main.fromRawJson(String str) => Main.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Main.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Main(
        temp: json["temp"].toDouble(),
        feelsLike: json["feels_like"].toDouble(),
        tempMin: json["temp_min"].toDouble(),
        tempMax: json["temp_max"].toDouble(),
        pressure: json["pressure"],
        humidity: json["humidity"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "temp": temp,
        "feels_like": feelsLike,
        "temp_min": tempMin,
        "temp_max": tempMax,
        "pressure": pressure,
        "humidity": humidity,
    };
}

class Sys {
    Sys({
        required this.type,
        required this.id,
        required this.country,
        required this.sunrise,
        required this.sunset,
    });

    final int type;
    final int id;
    final String country;
    final int sunrise;
    final int sunset;

    factory Sys.fromRawJson(String str) => Sys.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Sys.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Sys(
        type: json["type"],
        id: json["id"],
        country: json["country"],
        sunrise: json["sunrise"],
        sunset: json["sunset"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "id": id,
        "country": country,
        "sunrise": sunrise,
        "sunset": sunset,
    };
}

class WeatherElement {
    WeatherElement({
        required this.id,
        required this.main,
        required this.description,
        required this.icon,
    });

    final int id;
    final String main;
    final String description;
    final String icon;

    factory WeatherElement.fromRawJson(String str) => WeatherElement.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory WeatherElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => WeatherElement(
        id: json["id"],
        main: json["main"],
        description: json["description"],
        icon: json["icon"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "main": main,
        "description": description,
        "icon": icon,
    };
}

class Wind {
    Wind({
        required this.speed,
        required this.deg,
    });

    final double speed;
    final int deg;

    factory Wind.fromRawJson(String str) => Wind.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Wind.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Wind(
        speed: json["speed"].toDouble(),
        deg: json["deg"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "speed": speed,
        "deg": deg,
    };
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the weather data first into flutter?

Comment: I haven't tried this but it seems like it could work. I tried some other method advised by my coworker and it worked. But it's similiar to this.